# Invariants of $V^{\otimes N}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory, multilinear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional complex vector space, and $G = SL(V)$ be the group of linear transformations of $V$ with determinant $1$.

(a) Show that $V^{\otimes N}$ contains a nonzero $G$-invariant if and only if $N$ is a multiple of $\dim V$.

(b) If $N = m\dim V$ where $m$ is a positive integer, compute the dimension of the space of invariants $\left(V^{\otimes N}\right)^G$.

Comment: Unless you add some indication of your own level of knowledge about the subject, it will be hard to find out what is your difficulty with this question, and to answer the question. (Also it will get closed rapidly.)

Comment: For $\dim(V)=5$, $m=2$ (so $N=10$) the answer is $42$. (Whick makes this potentially  the "Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything";-). Maybe the right formula is not so simple.

Answer (score 2):

Let $d = \dim V$. By Schur-Weyl duality, as a representation of $S_N \times GL(V)$, $V^{\otimes N}$ decomposes as$$\bigoplus_{\lambda\text{ partition of }N} V_\lambda \otimes L_\lambda,$$where $V_\lambda$ is the Specht module and $L_\lambda$ is a representation of $GL(V)$. As a representation of $GL(V)$, the above collapses to$$\bigoplus_{\lambda\text{ partition of }N} \dim(V_\lambda)L_\lambda.\tag*{(1)}$$We know $L_\lambda = 0$ if $\lambda$ has more than $d$ rows. Otherwise, the dimension of $L_\lambda$ is given by$$\dim L_\lambda = \prod_{1 \le i < j \le d} {{\lambda_i - \lambda_j + j - i}\over{j-i}}.$$This is equal to $1$ only when $\lambda_1 = \dots = \lambda_d$, i.e. $\lambda_i = N/d$ for all $i$. If $v \in V^{\otimes N}$ is a nonzero $G$-invariant, then $\text{span}(v) \in \text{dim}(V_\lambda)L_\lambda$ is the decomposition $(1)$ with $\lambda$ defined as above. This is because $GL(V)v = \mathbb{C}SL(V)v = \text{span}(v)$, so $\text{span}(v)$ is a one-dimensional subrepresentation of $V^{\otimes N}$ under $GL(V)$. hence by Schur's Lemma it must actually be contained in $\dim(V_\lambda)L_\lambda$.

In particular, if $N$ is not a multiple of $d$, then $V$ has no invariants. From now on, suppose $N = dm$. The character of $L_\lambda$ is$$\chi_{L_\lambda}(g) = {{\det\left[x_i^{\lambda_j + d - j}\right]_{i, j}}\over{\det\left[x_i^{d-j}\right]_{i, j}}} = (x_1\dots x_d)^m,$$where $x_i$ are the eigenvalues of $g$; when $g \in SL(V)$ the above equals $1$. Hence $SL(V)$ acts trivially on $L_\lambda$.

By $(1)$, the dimension of the space of invariants is $\dim V_\lambda$ where $\lambda = (\underbrace{m,\dots, m}_d)$. By the hook length formula $($see [Pavel Etingof's notes on representation theory](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-712-introduction-to-representation-theory-fall-2010/lecture-notes/MIT18_712F10_ch4.pdf)$)$,$$\begin{align*}
\dim(V_{\lambda})=\frac{n!}{\prod_{i\leq \lambda_j} h(i,j)}
=\begin{cases}
\frac{(md)!}{(m+d-1)(m+d-2)^2\dots m^d (m-1)^d\dots (d+1)^dd^d (d-1)^{d-1}\dots 1^1} & \text{if }d\leq m\\
\frac{(md)!}{(m+d-1)(m+d-2)^2\dots d^m (d-1)^m\dots (m+1)^mm^m (m-1)^{m-1}\dots 1^1} & \text{if }d> m
\end{cases}
\end{align*}.
$$In particular, there exists a nonzero invariant.